# How to connect html to a node.js/express backend?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express

I've been searching around and couldn't find a good solution to this. 
I'm working on a school project that built upon HTML (Making a bunch of pages) -> CSS (Styling the pages) -> JS (Adding some functionality) and finally backend using whatever we want.

I've used mongodb and node/express to have a functional sign up and login and it works via POSTMAN, but I'm not sure how to connect that to my existing html file that was made for a prototype sign up/login.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

There's several things you need to consider.

If the goal is to authenticate users through your backend you need a way for your front end to communicate to the backend and check whether or not the user is logged in. To do this you'll need the express server to validate the user's login information and send a token back to the user. The user can then use this token to access protected routes on the server.

You can send a POST request to your server containing the login information with the axios library, and have the server redirect the user to a protected url upon a successful request.

I couldn't explain how to do this in this post alone, but here's an excellent tutorial on how to get started.

[authentication tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYQSCk-qyTW2ewJ05f_GKHtTIzjynDgjK)

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you already know what to use for backend, but not frontend.
You need to choose frontend such as React, Angular or Vue.js etc.
and connect your backend to the Server if it makes sense to you.

I recommend to look up React tutorial ( Or any other Frontend ) and move your HTML, CSS and JS to the project first.

Comment: I did follow a MERN example to help create the sign in/registration so I do know how to work with React a bit now at least, but because the project is basically all in html still I was wondering if I could just connect the two. 

It'd be a bit hard to redo every single page though, is it possible to link react pages to HTML or will I just have to port everything?

Thanks again for the help though!

Comment: I think you can turn the HTML files into JS files? Not 100% sure if it would work tho. But worth to try. Good luck!